# Does Azure "Sql Databases" (managed relational database-as-a-service) support SharePoint databases?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, amazon-rds

What I am trying to find out is during SharePoint installation (lets say in an Azure VM), can I use "Sql Databases" to create numerous DBs created by SharePoint? I am asking this because I recently went through this exercise in AWS only to find out that RDS (AWS variant of RDBMS as a service) does not support SharePoint databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using Azure SQL Database is not a supported configuration when running SharePoint in Azure Virtual Machines.  You can provision Virtual Machines running SQL Server though (recommended).

Here is a guide that walks you through considerations for running SharePoint workloads in Azure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn275958.aspx